# Cant execute binary on offline machine

Tags: 64-bit, executable

Im getting the output: `cannot execute binary file` when trying to execute a binary.
In my research i just found solutions for architecture, permissions and 64 / 32 bit problems.

I run on both systems 64 bit x86 processors. No ARM. I did set the executable permissions.

```
   file binary
binary: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=eac437fc2642b3b1c36ebaada419dbb121d8b66c, with debug_info, not stripped


uname -a
Linux air 5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

i tried to execute writing: `. binary`

thankful for any idea...

Comment: `. binary` attempts to *source* the binary into your shell; to *run* it (assuming it is located in your current directory, `.`) use `./binary`. See for example [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i)

Comment: omg that solved it. now it seems like it was stupid question :)
Thank you @steeldriver
if you want put your comment as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`. binary` attempts to *source* the binary file into your current shell

To run it, assuming it is located in your current directory, `./`, use `./binary`

See for example [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i)